# How to compare dates in SQL?

Tags: date

In a database table I have made a date attribute, but I have set its type to `varchar` and not `Date`. My question is: will I still be able to compare such dates in a SQL Query?

Dates in my DB are stored in this format:

> dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I have to do a SQL Query in PHP that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBtable
WHERE DBname='$name' AND date>='31/01/2015' AND date<='31/09/2015';
```

'date' looks like this: `07/08/2015 15:15:02`

I would appreciate an example of how to do this.

Comment: Please [edit] and [tag your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) to tell us which database product you are using (e.g. MySQL and version). Also, since it is pretty much always better to store dates as `dates` rather than strings, is there some reason you cannot change the table definition now? Or are you also asking for help doing that?

Comment: Are you able to change the date attribute to datetime?  Storing dates as varchar is problematic.  You will run into situations where data is stored that is not a valid date.  You will also be continuously converting to and from datetime.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what Database you are using, you should be able to cast the string to a date and then do your comparison.

i.e. in Sql Server

```
cast(date as datetime) >= '20150131' ...
```

That said, I'd typically recommend storing the date as a date if at all possible, and if you do need to use strings, It'd be best to use a more standardized format

i.e.
`'YYYY-mm-dd'` or even better `'YYYYmmdd'` instead of `'mm/dd/YYYY'` which, for example, can easily be mixed up with `'dd/mm/YYYY'` which is common in many cultures. See this blog post: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: and it's usually recommended to use a standard fromat for dates, like `'YYYY-mm-dd'` or even better `'YYYYmmdd'` and not the `'mm/dd/YYYY'` which is ambiguous and its interpretation by SQL-Server depends on local settings.

Comment: @ypercube, Agreed, updated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a question of "Which database are you using?"

Each RDBMS has it's own way of handling the problem.

If it's MySQL use str_to_date:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

This will convert a varchar to a date, and makes it possible to sort the date correctly.  Sorting a date as a varchar datatype will lead to some unexpected behavior.